# Sending automatic emails from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I get this error in my code an I'm unsure why... can ANYONE help???

Syntax error. (line 20, file "Code")

```
Line 18 - var emailSent = row[4]; // Third column

Line 19 -     if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates

Line 20 -       var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";

Line 21 -       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

Line 22 -      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
```

Comment: Syntax error means the machine can't understand your JavaScript.  You might be missing a `)`, `}`, something like that.  Post the complete code to get better help.  There's nothing wrong with line 20 itself.

Comment: Please share more of your code.  And you might like to take a look at [mcve].